# Multi Domain Infopath Code Signing with In House CA

Tags: sharepoint, infopath, certificate

We have forms developed in infopath that work with Sharepoint 2007. In order to deploy these forms to local clients you need to sign them with a certificate. We have an in house CA that is inside a domain that is part of a multi domain forest. Everything works ok for users in that specific domain. However users from other domains in the forest cannot use the forms since the certificates are not valid for them.

How can I get this certificate to sign the code for multiple domains and not just one domain?

I have found *Subject Alternative Names* for other scenarios but I'm not sure that will work in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add the CA certificate to the trusted roots in the other domains then the certificates will be valid in those domains as well.

certutil –dspublish "LDAP://[server]/[DN]?cACertificate?base?objectClass=certificationAuthority" [cert-file]